# Nested try-catch IOException inside catch for FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, filenotfoundexception, ioexception

I feel like nesting try-catch logic inside a catch block is not ideal / not clean code, but I am not sure how to refactor my code such that:

When there is no file found (catch FileNotFoundExeption) my program will create a new file (which generates IOException), without nesting the try catch.

```
public String hiMessage() {
        String message = "Hello! Initializing program.\n";

        try {
            storage.readFromTasksFileToList(tasks);
            message += "This is where you left off previously:\n";
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            message += "Fetching failed. " + e.getMessage() + "\n";
            message += "Creating file now...\n";
            File dukeTxt = new File(Duke.filePath);
            try { // nested try catch inside catch
                dukeTxt.createNewFile(); // throws IOException 
                message += "File created! " + dukeTxt.getAbsolutePath() + "\n";
                message += "Reading file...\n";
            } catch (IOException ioe) { 
                message += "\t File creation was not successful. \n";
                message += "\t Exiting system.";
                return message;
            }

        }

        message += getAllTasksAsString(); 
        return message;
    }
```

Comment: Are `tasks` and `dukeTxt` related?

Comment: You could just add a clean check to see that file exists

Comment: @Prashant I need to read a file containing tasks (dukeTxt) into an `ArrayList<Task> tasks`

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should check the existance of the file before reading it. Something along these lines:

```
File dukeTxt = new File(Duke.filePath);
if (dukeTxt.exist()) {
    try { dukeTxt.createNewFile(); }
    catch(IOException ioe) {...}
}
try { storage.readFromTasksFileToList(tasks); }
catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {...}
```

Comment: :) yes! I was handtyping and missed the `!`